# Pipe result to multiple commands without writing on screen

Tags: bash, tee

I have a very big zip file (~10 GB) which I want to unzip, and the result has to be passed to two commands. The results of both subsequent commands have to be appended to a file, and

Currently, I run

```
unzip -p bigFile.zip | head -n 1 >> output.txt
unzip -p bigFile.zip | grep -v 'skipLine' >> output.txt
```

which gives about a million rows. Now, I want to do it in 1 line. Using `tee`, I came up with

```
unzip -p bigFile.zip | tee >(head -n 1 >> output.txt) >(grep -v 'skipLine' 
>> output.txt)
```

But then the `output.txt` file only contains 51 rows, of which the last line is not even complete. Also, the latter command prints the results to the terminal, which I do not want.

I have also tried

```
unzip -p bigFile.zip | tee >(head -n 1 >> output.txt) | grep -v 'skipLine' 
>> output.txt
```

but unfortunately, this did not work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated! It is not necessary to use `tee`, any other command works fine, as long as I can pass the output of the `unzip` part to both the `head` and `grep` commands.

**EDIT:** It would be even better if the outputs of the `head` and `grep` commands could be 'combined' and then passed to `zip`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can unzip, and pipe into a shell script that consumes and prints the first line and allows grep to consume the rest:

```bsh
unzip -p bigFile.zip | {
    IFS= read -r header       # consume the first line, verbatim
    printf "%s\n" "$header"
    grep -v 'skipLine' 
} >> output.txt
```

Everything printed from the block is appended to the output file.

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a way to pipe to two separate commands like that, but you can use `awk` instead:

```
unzip -p file.zip | awk 'NR==1 || !/skipLine/' > output
```

The awk command will print the current line if it is the first line (`NR==1`) or if it doesn't match `skipline` (`!/skipLine`).

The best I can come up with combining `grep` and `head` is:

```
unzip -p file.zip | tee >(head -n1 > output) | tail -n+2 | grep -v skipLine >> output
```

The idea is to first catch the first line with `head -n1` and then use `tail -n+2` to print everything except the first line and this is then passed to `grep`. But just use the `awk` approach, it's simpler and easier.

Comment: My first reaction was `unzip | { IFS= read -r header; echo "$header"; grep -v skipLine; } > file` but I like the awk a lot better.

Comment: @Quasímodo whoops, I had forgotten to append the output to `output` in the second one, thanks.

Comment: @glennjackman ooh, I hadn't considered using `read` to read and discard the first line, that's neat! Worth its own answer, I think.

Comment: @terdon Welcome! I'm still worried about concurrency though: Aren't Grep and Head in a race condition there?

Comment: @Quasímodo I... don't know, actually. I don't think it would be an issue though since `head -n1` consumes the 1st line and `tail -n+2` only prints the rest. I think it is safe(ish) to assume that `head -n1 > output` will always finish before ` tail -n+2 | grep ...` so I think there will never be a problem. I would be interested to know if I'm wrong though!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm missing a subtle point, but it looks like you want to keep the first line and then anything after the first that does not contain the unique text `skipLine`. Seems like `sed` would handle that nicely.

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -n '1 {p;d}         #for line 1, print and discard
        /skipLine/d     #delete any line with skipLine
        p               #print remainder
' << End_of_SampleData
head
prefix skipLine
keepLine
skipLine suffix
keepLine
End_of_SampleData
```

Output:

```
head
keepLine
keepLine
```

You can just pipe your data into this script `unzip -p bigFile.zip | sed ...` if this test case matches your requirements. This should be pretty quick since there is just one `unzip` and one `sed` process to run.

Comment: `{p;d}` is different to what's in the question, where any line that passes both filters will appear twice.  It seems we just want `p` there.

Comment: Oh, and that `//d;p` is more simply written `//!p`, since they are the last commands in the program.  That gives a simpler script: `sed -n -e 1p -e '/skipLine/!p'`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems you're experiencing with your `tee` command:

> ```
> tee >(head -n 1 >>output.txt) >(grep -v 'skipLine' >>output.txt)
> ```

The easy one is that you want to discard the output.  To do that, you could simply send standard output to /dev/null:

```
tee >(head -n 1 >>output.txt) >(grep -v 'skipLine' >>output.txt) >/dev/null
```

But that seems wasteful; it's more efficient connect the second command to `tee`'s standard out:

```
tee >(head -n 1 >>output.txt) | grep -v 'skipLine' >>output.txt
```

The second is that `head` closes its input after reading as much input as it needs.  The simple fix is to follow that with a process that discards its input:

```
tee >(head -n 1 >>output.txt; dd of=/dev/null) | grep -v skipLine >>output.txt
```

We might replace the two opens of `output.txt` with a single one, if we want this pipeline to replace any previous content:

```
exec 3>output.txt
tee >(head -n 1 >&3; dd of=/dev/null) | grep -v skipLine >&3
```

Do note that in all these versions, there's no guarantee that the head line will be at the beginning of the output file, unlike the initial version with two separate pipelines.  If that's a requirement, then look at one of the other answers for replacements (or take a gamble with an arbitrary `sleep` sequenced before the `grep`).

But I hope this answer helps you *understand* why you see the results that you do, rather than just spoon-feeding alternatives.

Comment: You asked for the outputs to be recombined - that's what happens in the last version, and it's not hard to redirect to a pipe rather than file.